# Pandas dataframe: df.shape throws error 'TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable'

Tags: python, pandas, dimensions

### Background

I am trying to get shape of a dataframe. I read the data from from a csv file to a dataframe using pd.read_csv and then am trying ro get its dimensions.

### Code

```
file_name = 'xxxxxx.csv'

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    metadata_location = [i for i, x in enumerate(f.readlines()) if 'Metadata' in x]

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=False, skipfooter=26)
print(data.shape())
```

### Error

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

How to resolve it???????

### Other checks

```
print(type(data))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: simply call `data = pd.read_csv(file_name, index_col=False, skipfooter=26)` without open

Comment: Same error again 'TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable'

Comment: remove the () after shape. its an property not a class method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is because shape() throws error, the correct way is without parenthesis.

If you change:

```
print(data.shape())
```

For:

```
print(data.shape)
```

It will print the shape of data

Do you really need the second: with open... ? Pandas can load without the with open line

Comment: I just were answering and saw your coment after, sorry for the confusion @luigigi, but I tried that and saw the error in my jupyter notebook when your comment was not posted yet, at least in my answer loaded page.